# Mapstruct mapping with condition and nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I apologize if the title is not clear, let me make it clear by giving sample codes:

**UpdateProfileDto**

```
public class UpdateProfileDto {

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @Size(max = 20)
    private String currentPassword;

    @Size(max = 20)
    private String newPassword;

    @Size(max = 20)
    private String confirmNewPassword;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**EncodedMapping**

```
@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface EncodedMapping {
}
```

**PasswordEncoderMapper**

```
public class PasswordEncoderMapper {
    protected final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public PasswordEncoderMapper(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @EncodedMapping
    public String encode(String value) {
        return passwordEncoder.encode(value);
    }
}
```

**UserMapper**

```
@Mapper(config = MapperConfig.class, componentModel = "spring", uses = PasswordEncoderMapper.class)
public interface UserMapper {

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "firstName", source = "firstName"),
            @Mapping(target = "lastName", source = "lastName"),
            @Mapping(target = "fullName", expression = "java(user.getFirstName() + \" \" + user.getLastName())"),
            @Mapping(target = "password",
                    source = "newPassword",
                    nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE,
                    qualifiedBy = EncodedMapping.class)
    })
    void updateUserFromDto(UpdateUserProfileDto updateUserProfileDto, @MappingTarget User user);
}
```

**Generated UserMapperImpl**

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-03-11T13:51:34+0800",
    comments = "version: 1.3.0.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_231 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class UserMapperImpl implements UserMapper {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoderMapper passwordEncoderMapper;

    @Override
    public void updateUserFromDto(UpdateUserProfileDto updateUserProfileDto, User user) {
        if ( updateUserProfileDto == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( updateUserProfileDto.getFirstName() != null ) {
            user.setFirstName( updateUserProfileDto.getFirstName() );
        }
        else {
            user.setFirstName( null );
        }
        if ( updateUserProfileDto.getLastName() != null ) {
            user.setLastName( updateUserProfileDto.getLastName() );
        }
        else {
            user.setLastName( null );
        }
        if ( updateUserProfileDto.getNewPassword() != null ) {
            user.setPassword( passwordEncoderMapper.encode( updateUserProfileDto.getNewPassword() ) );
        }

        user.setFullName( user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() );
    }
}
```

From the generated `UserMapperImpl`, I would like to check not only if `newPassword` has value... but to check `currentPassword` and `newPassword` have values and proceed with `user.setPassword()`.

I mean something like this:

```
...
if ( updateUserProfileDto.getCurrentPassword() != null && updateUserProfileDto.getNewPassword() != null ) {
    user.setPassword( passwordEncoderMapper.encode( updateUserProfileDto.getNewPassword() ) );
}
...
```

**Problem**

How could I change my mapper interface `UserMapper` so that i will check both `currentPassword` and `newPassword` before it will set the target `user.password` and will still use `PasswordEncoderMapper.encode(password)`?

If I try to use `expression` instead of `source` and check both `currentPassword` and `newPassword` if both have values and then set `user.password` to `newPassword`. Otherwise, it will not do anything to `user.password`using `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy`... but it seems it is not allowede to mix `expression` and `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with following approach

```java
@Mapper(config = MapperConfig.class, componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class UserMapper { // using class instead of interface to be able to inject beans

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoderMapper passwordEncoderMapper;

    @Mappings({
            // your non-password mappings
    })
    void updateUserFromDto(UpdateUserProfileDto updateUserProfileDto, @MappingTarget User user);


    @AfterMapping
    void setPassword(UpdateUserProfileDto updateUserProfileDto, @MappingTarget User user) {
        if (updateUserProfileDto.getCurrentPassword() != null && updateUserProfileDto.getNewPassword() != null) {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoderMapper.encode( updateUserProfileDto.getNewPassword()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to add a presence check for new password that would check both the current and new. That way MapStruct would use the presence check.